# I want to get previous path on a button click event in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, back

### Get previous location path on back button click event using by angular.js

---

**What I want?**

I want to go previous page when i click the  back button in my current page.

***HTML***

```
<input type="button" ng-click="back()" />
```

***Controller***

```
$scope.back=function()
{
// here i want to get the previous path(or url) 
}
```

---

---

**What I did**

I can get the prev url by using on `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess`

```
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
        var old = absOldUrl
    });
```

I don't want this way, i want to get the previous `URL` on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function back() {
    parent.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain about the parent?

Comment: it refers to the parent of the current frame, you can also use window instead of parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
    absOldUrl=absOldUrl.substring(9);
    var aaa = absOldUrl.indexOf("/");
    $rootScope.PrevURL = absOldUrl.substring(aaa + 1);

    absNewUrl = absNewUrl.substring(9);
    var aaa = absNewUrl.indexOf("/");
    $rootScope.NextURL = absOldUrl.substring(aaa + 1);

    console.log($rootScope.PrevURL);
    console.log($rootScope.NextURL);
    })
})
```